# Getting error Uncaught Error: [vuex] getters should be function but "getters.getters" is {}. in VUEX store when store is split into modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, getter

I am new to VUEX and build a test application while learning VUEX. I have split my VUEX store into modules with each module having its own getter.js file. Getters, actions, mutations are imported into individual index.js for each module which is further imported into the main store index.js file. I am getting the error "Uncaught Error: [vuex] getters should be function but "getters.getters" is {}." on the browser while displaying the website. Also I was trying to achieve this with the map helpers

Can someone please help me resolve this error. Details are available below for the file content

Folder structure:

```
store
 modules
  coaches
   action.js
   getter.js
   action.js
   index.js
  requests
   action.js
   getter.js
   action.js
   index.js
 index.js
```

**coaches/index.js file content is:**

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import mutations from "./mutations.js";
import actions from "./actions.js";
import getters from './getter.js';

export default createStore({
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
      coaches: [
        {
          id: "c1",
          firstname: "Gau",
          lastname: "Rau",
          area: "[finance,javascript,analysis]",
          description: "devloper for fun",
          age: "38",
        },
        {
          id: "c2",
          firstname: "Ran",
          lastname: "Bi",
          area: "[insurance,SQL,analysis]",
          description: "photographer for fun",
          age: "37",
        }
      ]
    },
  mutations: mutations,
  actions: actions,
  getters: {getters},
});

**coaches/getter.js file content:**

   

     export default {
            coacheslist(state){
                return state.coaches;
            },
            hasCoaches(state){
                return state.coaches && state.coaches.length >0;
            }
        };

**store/index.js file content is:**

import { createStore } from "vuex";
import CoachModule from "./modules/coaches/index.js";
import RequestModule from "./modules/requests/index.js";

export default createStore({
  modules: {
    Coaches: CoachModule, 
    Requests: RequestModule}
});

**File content which calls the getter:**

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    filteredCoaches(){
      return this.$store.getters['Coaches/coacheslist']
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

looks like the problem is that you're defining getters as an object with 1 parameter of `getters`. Change that just just `getters: getters`, or even better embrace ES6 and write that like

```
export default createStore({
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
      ...
  },
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters,
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Usage of ES6 did sort out the error. But now I am getting the below error. Does that mean the way I have written the getter.js file is incorrect?                                                                             "Uncaught Error: [vuex] getters should be function but "getters.coacheslist" in module "Coaches" is [{"id":"c1","firstname":"Gau","lastname":"Rau","area":"[finance,javascript,analysis]","description":"devloper for fun","age":"38"},{"id":"c2","firstname":"Ran","lastname":"Bis","area":"[insurance,SQL,analysis]","description":"photographer for fun","age":"37"}]."

Answer (score 0):

Try to change getters importing on:

```
import * as getters from './getters'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to solve the issue which was due to createStore being added to one of the getter file in error. Thanks a lot for response